# English proof for decomposition of modular polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, translation

Let $\Phi_n(X,Y)$ be the modular polynomial that are the canonical equations for the modular curve $X_0(n)$. They parameterise pairs of elliptic curves related by a cyclic isogeny of degree $n$.

I am looking for proofs for the following two results:

1. If $m=p^a$, where $p$ is prime and $a>1$, then
   $$\Phi_m(X,Y)=\begin{cases}
   \dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^{\Psi(p^{a-1})}\Phi_p(X,\xi_i)}{\Phi_{p^{a-2}}(X,Y)^p}\,, & a>2\,,\\[0.5cm]
   \dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^{p+1}\Phi_p(X,\xi_i)}{(X-Y)^{p+1}}\,, & a=2\,,
   \end{cases}$$
   where $\xi_i$ are the roots of $\Phi_{p^{a-1}}(X,Y)=0$, and $\Psi(m)=m\prod_{p\mid m}(1+1/p)$.
2. If $p^e$ is the $p$-primary part of $n$ and if we write $n=n'p^e$, then $\Phi_n(X,Y)$ splits modulo $p$ as follows:
   $$\Phi_n(X,Y) = \Phi_{n'}\left( X^{p^{e-1}}, Y \right) \Phi_{n'}\left( X, Y^{p^{e-1}} \right)\prod_{i=1}^{e-1} \Phi_{n'}\left( X^{p^{e-i-1}}, Y^{p^{i-1}} \right)^{p-1}\pmod{p}\,.$$

I found the first result as (13.14) in David Cox's *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* but he refers the reader to Weber's *Lehrbuch der Algebra*.

The next result is found in Igusa's *Kroneckerian Model of Fields of Elliptic Modular Functions* and the reader was asked to refer to *Die typen der multiplikatorenringe elliptischer funktionenkörper* by Max Deuring.

I will be very happy if someone could provide a reference to proofs of these in english or direct me to english readings that would allow me to develop these proofs. THANKS!

Comment: What is $\Phi_m(X,Y)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, Klein-Fricke (auf Deutsch) is really the ultimate resource for this.

Comment: @paulgarrett Hi Paul, I was wondering if there are english references that deal with the concepts involved in the proofs. For example, Deuring mentions the number subfields of "Elliptische funktionenkörper" and also automorphisms but I have no idea where to look for more information.

Comment: As far as in-English (and, therefore, probably contemporary) sources for these things, I don't know. Shimura's 1970 treatment was innovative for its time, and/but such things do deserve... updating. I did read Deuring years ago, and it was unsatisfying insofar as it was computation-intensive, and not at all conceptual. Arguably, the "elemental" ideas sketched in Klein-Fricke should be put into English, and I might do it myself some time, but I do not know of a high-profile source in English for this at the moment. I've not been paying attention, though, ...